# How do I include a variable in a block of code inside a script tag in Pug

Tags: javascript, pug

I've this Pug mixin:

```
mixin myMixin(options)
    - if (!options) options = {}
    script.
        var myObject = {
            "page": {
                "id": "",
                "title": document.title,
                "url": location.href,
                "breadcrumb": options.breadcrumb ? options.breadcrumb : [],
                "timestamp": new Date()
            }
        }
```

And this is what it compiles to:

```
<script>
    var myObject = {
        "page": {
            "id": "",
            "title": document.title,
            "url": location.href,
            "breadcrumb": options.breadcrumb ? options.breadcrumb : [],
            "timestamp": new Date()
        }
    }
</script>
```

I am not sure how do I make the 'option.breadcrumb' variable work which Pug compiles. I am looking for the compiled code to have the value of the options.breadcrumb property or an empty array.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You have to use interpolation](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html)

```js
<script>
    var breadcrumb = '!{options.breadcrumb}';

    var myObject = {
        "page": {
            "id": "",
            "title": document.title,
            "url": location.href,
            "breadcrumb": breadcrumb ? breadcrumb : [],
            "timestamp": new Date()
        }
    }
</script>
```